# exoplayer MediaItem setClippingConfiguration not working if using CacheDataSource

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x, android-media3, exoplayer-media-item

my code is:

```
val mediaItem: MediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(recitationUri)
        .setMediaId("$surah:${ayah}")
        .setClippingConfiguration(
            ClippingConfiguration.Builder()
                .setStartPositionMs(ayahTiming.start)
                .setEndPositionMs(ayahTiming.end)
                .build()
        ).build()


    val mediaSourceFactory = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(MediaCache.getInstance(this@PlaybackService).cacheFactory)
    val source = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(mediaItem)
```

and MediaCache class is :

```
const val CACHE_DIR_NAME = "cached_audio"
const val MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 256 * 1024 * 1024L//256MB

class MediaCache private constructor(context: Context) {

val cacheFactory: CacheDataSource.Factory

init {
    cacheFactory = setupExoPlayerCache(context)
}

companion object {
    @Volatile
    private lateinit var instance: MediaCache

    fun getInstance(context: Context): MediaCache {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (!::instance.isInitialized) {
                instance = MediaCache(context)
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
private fun setupExoPlayerCache(context: Context): CacheDataSource.Factory {
    val cacheEvictor = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
    val databaseProvider = StandaloneDatabaseProvider(context)
    val cache = SimpleCache(
        File(context.cacheDir, CACHE_DIR_NAME),
        cacheEvictor, databaseProvider
    )
    val upstreamFactory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
    return CacheDataSource.Factory().apply {
        setCache(cache)
        setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(upstreamFactory)
        setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)
    }
}
```

}

I don't know why using this code `ClippingConfiguration` is not working :

```
val mediaSourceFactory = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(MediaCache.getInstance(this@PlaybackService).cacheFactory)
val source = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(mediaItem)
```

but working if using simple media source:

```
val source = DefaultMediaSourceFactory(this).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

using `DefaultMediaSourceFactory` instead of `ProgressiveMediaSource` solves my problem.

```
val mediaSourceFactory = DefaultMediaSourceFactory(MediaCache.getInstance(this@PlaybackService).cacheFactory)
val source = mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(mediaItem)
```